# Autodesk Forge File Conversion how to download files in manifest?

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Following the Model Derivative "Prepare a File for the Viewer" after I have successfully uploaded and converted file I call the manifest url

how do I then download the converted files in the manifest. If I only know the refrence urn?
(i.e.) How would I get the coverted svf          "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bW9kZWxkZXJpdmF0aXZlL0E1LnppcA/output/1/A5.svf"

or the thumbnail
"urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bW9kZWxkZXJpdmF0aXZlL0E1LnppcA/output/1/A5.svf.png01_thumb_200x200.png"

Is there a api call that can be used to return the actual location?

Edit: The end result is I want to create something like the [extractor] (http://extract.autodesk.io/) does. With all the files I need to run the viewer locally

Edit2:The Manifest I get back from call after fileUploda

```
Result{
  "type": "manifest",
  "hasThumbnail": "true",
  "status": "success",
  "progress": "complete",
  "region": "US",
  "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Z3JlZ2JpbWJ1Y2tldC9yYWNfYmFzaWNfc2FtcGxlX3Byb2plY3RfdGVzdC5ydnQ",
  "derivatives": [
    {
      "name": "rac_basic_sample_project_test.rvt",
      "hasThumbnail": "true",
      "status": "success",
      "progress": "complete",
      "outputType": "svf",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "{3D}",
          "hasThumbnail": "true",
          "role": "3d",
          "status": "success",
          "type": "geometry",
          "progress": "complete",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "{3D}",
              "role": "3d",
              "camera": [
             ...
              ],
              "status": "success",
              "type": "view",
              "progress": "complete"
            },
            {
              "type": "resource",
              "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Z3JlZ2JpbWJ1Y2tldC9yYWNfYmFzaWNfc2FtcGxlX3Byb2plY3RfdGVzdC5ydnQ/output/Resource/3D_View/_3D_/_3D_.svf",
              "role": "graphics",
              "mime": "application/autodesk-svf"
            },
            {
              "type": "resource",
              "role": "thumbnail",
              "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Z3JlZ2JpbWJ1Y2tldC9yYWNfYmFzaWNfc2FtcGxlX3Byb2plY3RfdGVzdC5ydnQ/output/Resource/3D_View/_3D_/_3D_1.png",
              "resolution": [
                100,
                100
              ],
              "mime": "image/png",
              "status": "success"
            },
```

The Request I try to send but get a 404

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Z3JlZ2JpbWJ1Y2tldC9yYWNfYmFzaWNfc2FtcGxlX3Byb2plY3RfdGVzdC5ydnQ/manifest/urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Z3JlZ2JpbWJ1Y2tldC9yYWNfYmFzaWNfc2FtcGxlX3Byb2plY3RfdGVzdC5ydnQ/output/Resource/3D_View/_3D_/_3D_1.png
```

Is there anything wrong with that call to modelderivative?

Comment: are you using the endpoint to download derivatives? https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-derivativeurn-GET/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [derivativeurn GET](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-derivativeurn-GET/) worked

I also had to make sure the derivativeUrn was encoded

(JAVA)     derivativeUrn = URLEncoder.encode(derivativeUrn, "UTF-8");

Answer (score 0):

Cyrille Fauvel implemented this, so it is in his GitHub repo:

https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io

https://github.com/cyrillef/extract-php-view.and.data.api

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at [the implementation of the NPM View & Data Package](https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/view-and-data-npm/blob/master/view-and-data.js#L813) for the time being. It is still using the v1 API endpoints but we are currently working on providing wrappers for multiple programming languages on the v2 endpoints