# ModelDeriviate's manifest is missing URN for SVF2

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I know that it is possible to download the derivatives via their respective `urn`s. However, the SVF2 object in the manifest doesn't contain its `urn`. Therefore, I cannot download the derivative as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58424435/4295853) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441808/autodesk-forge-file-conversion-how-to-download-files-in-manifest). Is this not supported yet? And can I compute the `urn` from the data returned in the manifest?

Extract of an manifest example:

```json
{
    "urn": "SOME_URN",
    "derivatives": [
        {
            "hasThumbnail": "true",
            "children": [
                {
                    "useAsDefault": true,
                    "role": "3d",
                    "hasThumbnail": "true",
                    "children": [
                        {
                           ...
                        },
                        {
                           ...
                        },
                        {
                            "role": "graphics",
                            "mime": "application/autodesk-svf2",
                            "guid": "SOME_GUID",
                            "type": "resource"
                        }
                    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to make clear that it is possible to download the SVF2 'files' since your WEB browser can do it; therefore, you can access the data as well. The files are actually cached in your Browser, see below.

[image: SVF2 data cached]

The Viewer downloads an extra manifest files (otg_model.json) which contains additional information. But downloading the 'files' on your local machine will not help since it requires a lot of setup to get the Viewer work properly with a local SVF2 storage. And with the current state of the technology, it is highly recommended you do not try to do this in production. When it comes to development, and debugging, I go a sample posted [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge.commandline-nodejs) which can help. But please be careful with the Autodesk EULA on doing offline workflows. This sample is a replacement of the old extract.autodesk.io sample as people were abusing of this website, and can work with both SVF and SVF2.

To answer the question in the comment section. SVF2 is still in beta, and access to the underlying data/files will probably be only available at the end on the beta. The main reason is that SVF2 and the Viewer code evolves too rapidly today to make a general availability to everything. So unless you keep updating them on your local machine, things may break, and therefore Autodesk is limiting the access.

Comment: This means SVF2 can be used in a disconnected workflow like described in [this blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/disconnected-workflows)? Regarding the EULA, based on the mentioned blog post I assumed that Forge may be used temporarily offline. However, this may not be necessarily the case and you advise me to get the Autodesk EULA checked in detail?

Comment: @Dominik - you are correct, we call this the disconnected mode (rather than offline) - this is to make sure that when you loose connectivity, you can still continue to work. So this is permitted.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for disappointing you, but ...

Unfortunately, it's expected behavior. SVF2 doesn't have a concept of URN, and you cannot download SVF2 for offline viewing at this moment since it's unsupported.

Comment: Is it currently unsupported because if the beta phase and will it be either supported in the future or remain unsupported indefenitely?

Comment: @eason-kang is this something that is going to be available in the future?